# php foreach loop, using continue results in $key always being 0

Tags: php

```
<?php

$honorifics = array("None", "Miss", "Ms.", "Mrs.", "Mr.", " Mx", " Dr.", "Prof.", "Rabbi", "Reverend", "Imam");
?>

<?php foreach ($honorifics as $index => $honor){
        if ($index = 0) {
          continue;
        }
        echo ( $index );
}?>
```

prints out

00000000

why?

I saw that removing the continue fixes the problem, but thats not what I want. I wan't to understand what's going wrong.

how to fix?

Comment: change `$index = 0` to `$index == 0`,  `=` is assignment operator while `==` in comparison operator

Comment: why does this not throw an error?

Comment: because it is a perfectly valid code

Comment: because it dont have any error :)

Comment: how is that ever valid? i mean that's bullshit. The if should require an expression. What I am giving is I assign a variable. You cannot even argue that the result `if(0)` because I assign a parameter, I am not handing it to the `if`

Comment: `if($index = 0; $index)` that should create said error. Not my code though.

Comment: in php (and other languages I assume, don't know them all) you can set variable data in a condition, it is quite error prone but in some cases it can be useful, see my edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($index = 0) {
    continue;
}
```

store 0 value to `$index` variable, what you want is `if ($index == 0)` or, better `if (!$index)`

In php (and other languages I assume) you can set a variable data in a condition, this is often not what you want ans should be avoided, but sometimes can be useful, take this example:

```
$len = $query->count()  // mysql query count()

if ($len) {
    // do stuff
}

// this can be shortened to

if ($len = $query->count()) {
    // do stuff if true
    echo $len;  // will echo the actual count()   
}
```

to avoid errors like this, I usually test my variables like this:

```
if (0 == $index)
```

this **WILL** throw an error if you miss your expression not on purpose :) but nowadays, when using IDE like phpstorm, netbeans or others, generally there is an inspection that warn you about that statement.

**EDIT**:

Here the inspection to enaable in PHPStorm:

[image]

And here the result:

[image]

Comment: I am using phpstorm and there was no inspection or warning

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `0` to `$index` in every loop and then checking.

```
if ($index = 0) {
```

would work same like -

```
$index = 0;
if($index) { // if(0) {
```

Which is `false` and which is perfectly fine. That's why it is not satisfying the condition and `$index`is printing `0` in every loop.

It should be -

```
if ($index === 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change this:

```
if ($index = 0) {
```

to this one:

```
if ($index == 0) {
```